# Gnuplot flashing output X-window when generating Pdf

Tags: gnuplot, x11

I am running Gnuplot on Ubuntu 13.10 to generate some pdf plots.

Now I run a sample plot `file1.gpl` written as -

```
set xrange [0.000000:780121.000000]
set yrange [0.200000:4.800000]
set autoscale x
set key off
set style line 12 lc rgb '#808080' lt 0 lw 1
set grid back ls 12
set palette model RGB
unset colorbox
set object 1 rectangle from 404644.000000, 0.8 to 408665.000000, 1.2 fillcolor rgb "#FFB300" fillstyle solid 0.8
plot -1 title "COLOR_0" with lines linecolor rgb "#FF9B73"  linewidth 6
```

And there is another file, which is like settings for me, used to generate the pdf output file.

```
set terminal pdfcairo size 12in,6in
set output "output.pdf"
replot
set output
```

I run the command as -

```
gnuplot file1.gpl settings.gpl
```

Now when I run this, it generates the PDF file correctly, without any problem. However a X-window flashes at the output momentarily which shows the plot. I would like to disable this momentarily flashing of the X-Window because I am running a plot generation in a script file, which results continuous flashing of output window.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just switch the two files. At the moment the first `plot` command is carried out, the default interactive terminal is set.

Change your `settings.gpl` to

```
set terminal pdfcairo size 12in,6in
set output 'output.pdf'
```

and call

```
gnuplot settings.gpl file1.gpl
```